# Unexpected identifier in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running a script from this repo https://github.com/barodeur/pocket-archive-all

The purpose is to archive all my pocket bookmarks

The code is very simple

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

npm install
source ./.env
nodemon --harmony app.js
```

I'm having the following error

```
npm install
    ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

How did you run it? It seems that you're using `node` to run that script but it's bash script.

Just install `npm` and then chmod the script to be executable and run it

```
./dev-server
```